# Populate 2 dependents dropdown lists from a database without page refresh in CSHTML using AJAX

Tags: c#, ajax, razor

I want to populate a first dropdownlist (Continent) and accordingly pouplate the list of that continent's countries from a database in the following format:

Name of the table: countries

Continent| Country

Africa   | Nigeria

Africa   | Marroco

Europe   | France

Europe   | Gernamy

Asia     | China

Asia     | India

My code looks like:

```
<html>
    @{

   var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
   var Contient=""; 

} 

<div class="container">
    <select  id="Continent" name="Continent" onchange="PopulateListCountry(this)">
         <option value="">Choose continent</option>
         @foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT DISTINCT Continent FROM countries;"))
            {
             <option value="@row.Continent">@row.Continent</option>
            }
     </select>

     <select name="Country" id="Country">
            <option value="">Choose country</option>

             @foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT Country FROM countries where continent=@0",@continent ))
             {
                <option value="@row.Country ">@row.Country </option>
             }
       </select>
</div> 
</html>
```

The variable @continent should correspond to the value selected from the first dropdownlist. 
The function PopulateListCountry should be written using ajax to fill the second list without page reload.

Is there any suggestion to make this work?
Thanks a lot!!